# Why is my ruby script not splitting the field in my CSV?

Tags: ruby, string, csv, split

Here is what my CSV looks like: http://tinypic.com/r/kuwk6/5

And here is my code:

```
File.open("/Users/Katie/Downloads/File_Name.csv", encoding: "ISO-8859-1").each_line do |line|

  line.chomp!
  CSV.parse(line, col_sep: "\t") do |row|
    unless row[4].nil?
      puts row[4].split("&Wt.srch=1")[0]
    end
  end
end
```

I had issues with special characters, which is why I have the encoding in there and because I'm on a Mac, when I open a CSV in excel, it does something weird to the rows, so I put in the line.chomp!.  The file is technically tab deliminated, so i did the col_sep for the tabs.

Basically I want the URL to be split at the "&Wt.srch=1" but I only want to have the first part of the string returned after it splits them, which is why I put the [0].

When I run the code without the "unless" row, it says `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method`split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

This makes me think that it thinks this column is empty, when in fact, it's not.  But of course when I put in the "unless" line, it runs the script just fine, but doesn't actually split the url string.

Sorry if this is a really basic / easy problem... Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `p row` to see what's actually being returned by `CSV.parse`?

Comment: Just tried that and it returns only the fields from the first column (on separate lines).  I guess that's a good place to start troubleshooting.  Why is it only returning the first column...  Thanks!

Comment: **update** I just checked, I had "puts row[0]" which is why it was only returning the first line, but when I took away the [0], it returned everything correctly.  Then I tried puts row[4] to see if in fact my column is blank, and it's not, it returns all of the URLs that I can see when I open the CSV.

Comment: Could you please include your sample CSV in your post, rather than a link to a picture of it. This will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `CSV.parse` do do this

**With tabs:**

File:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
Hello   Alpha   Example More    https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&Wt.srch=1&utm=2&utm2=blah
Thanks  Bravo   Example some    https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&Wt.srch=1&utm=2&utm2=blah
Blah    Charlie Example stuff   https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&Wt.srch=1&utm=2&utm2=blah
```

Script:

```
 #returns each_line of the csv file as a string
File.open("/Users/Katie/Downloads/File_Name.csv").each_line do |line|
  #splits the line at tab character into row Array
  row = line.chomp.split("\t")      
  unless row[4].nil?
    puts row[4].split("&Wt.srch=1")[0]
  end
end
```

Output:

```
c5
https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&
https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&
https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&
```

**With Commas:**

File:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
Hello,Alpha,Example,More,https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&Wt.srch=1&utm=2&utm2=blah
Thanks,Bravo,Example,some,https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&Wt.srch=1&utm=2&utm2=blah
Blah,Charlie,Example,stuff,https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&Wt.srch=1&utm=2&utm2=blah
```

Script:

```
 #returns each_line of the csv file as a string
File.open("/Users/Katie/Downloads/File_Name.csv").each_line do |line|
  #splits the line at tab character into row Array
  row = line.chomp.split(",")      
  unless row[4].nil?
    puts row[4].split("&Wt.srch=1")[0]
  end
end
```

Output:

```
c5
https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&
https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&
https://www.exampl.com?f1=1&
```

Script to handle the use of encoding with "ISO-8859-1":

```
File.open("/Users/Katie/Downloads/File_Name.csv", encoding: "ISO-8859-1").each_line do |line|
  #splits the line at tab character into row Array
  row = line.chomp.split(" ").delete_if{|r| r.strip.empty?}     
  unless row[4].nil?
    puts row[4].split("&Wt.srch=1")[0]
  end
end
```

The way you have it set up you are looping through the lines and then splitting the lines into individual strings using `CSV.parse` so row is actually a single "cell" not an array of cells.

Comment: I have tested this and it works as requested are you sure that your fields are delimited by tabs? If this is a standard CSV file then the split would be on comma. i.e. `row = line.chomp.split(",")`

Comment: I double checked by putting the file in my text editor and showed the invisible characters.  Definitely tab delimited.  No commas anywhere in the file.

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work for you then as I have shown the code was tested with both tabs and commas and functions as requested. If you could post the actual file instead of a screen shot I could try and debug directly against your file.

Comment: I'm creating a sample file from scratch to see if it works with a that file as opposed to my actual one. Thanks for your help!  Will let you know what happens!

Comment: OK, thanks so much for your help!  It was the encoding - I used sublime and opened the file and saved it with a different encoding (UTF-8), ran the script and it worked like a charm.  Have NO CLUE why this would matter, but it worked, so Thanks again!!!

Comment: Final note seems that `ISO-8859-1` tab character is actually `&#09;` not sure if this would make a difference for you